# how to make the google sheet query to return the value in sequence of first in

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

i had a set of data that is continuously changing and growing (adding to the bottom). So, i set a query formula to show value from the set of data into another sheet but it always return the value in first row and not at next line of the previous value.

this is the query formula

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xk0Cvafixr5dayJkBkrzlYLFoA4E_PHYfPNQis12rc8/edit#gid=0","CONSOLIDATE!A1:F"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col6 = '"&REFERENCE!E6&"'")
```

`REFERENCE!E6 =` is my conditional rule, so it shows only when there is a match with the values in this cell.

Can someone help me to change the query formula so that new values in `"CONSOLIDATE!A1:F"` it will appear at the next line of previous data (bottom) instead of top line?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by returning a value in the first row instead of the next line of the previous row?

Comment: The `query` is merely returning the data in the same order as appears on the other spreadsheet. But is there, perhaps, a date-related field that could be used to sort the query.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your comments by @Tedinoz, you could order your query by date and time, making the new rows appear on the bottom.

Here is some documentation showing [how to write queries](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) with "Order By" parameters.

Assuming Col1 and Col2 are your date and time columns, your query would look like:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xk0Cvafixr5dayJkBkrzlYLFoA4E_PHYfPNQis12rc8/edit#gid=0","CONSOLIDATE!A1:F"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col6 = '"&REFERENCE!E6&"' order by Col1, Col2")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ain Not a problem! Enjoy!
Also, remember to accept the answers that are useful to you!